# In c# how to prevent a class from being modified

Tags: c#, interface

Let's say I have an interface:

```
interface IPerson
{
   int Age { get; set; }
   string Name { get; set; }
   bool Alive { get; set; }
}
```

and a Class:

```
public class Person : IPerson
{
   public int Age { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

That would not compile since Person does not implement the `Alive` Property.

What I would like to know is if there is a way to have the same behaviour, if Person adds an extra property that is not found in its interface.

```
interface IPerson
{
   int Age { get; set; }
   string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and a Class:

```
public class Person : IPerson
{
   public int Age { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public bool Alive { get; set; }  <---- This should prevent it from compiling as well.
}
```

I would want it to not compile as well, or at the very least give me a compile warning.

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: From the compiler's perspective there's nothing wrong with adding properties to a class that implements an interface.  Why do you want this behavior?

Comment: By using the interface in your applications and not specifying the concrete class used, your application wouldn't know about the extra properties and methods anyway

Comment: I can't imagine a way of doing this.  Nor can I imagine a *reason* for doing this.  What actual problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: We had to create custom copy function to replace slow code that was using reflection.  We want to make sure all fields are mapped.  We do not trust people on the team to update the methods with new fields.  I was trying to think out of the box... Based on the immediate negative feedback, I guess that was wrong

Comment: _"We want to make sure all fields are mapped. We do not trust people on the team to update the methods with new fields.  I was trying to think out of the box"_ - here's an out-box suggestion: write a unit test that validates the properties of the class against the interface

Comment: Sadly, even this is not sufficient.  We wrote unit tests and coders still release new versions without running of those first.  So assuming they would is not realistic.  What I will end up doing is add some logic at beginning of program that will prevent it to run if any of the classes are changed.  That's the only way to be sure

Comment: _We wrote unit tests and coders still release new versions without running of those first_  How is this possible?   Your unit tests should be run as part of the build process!

Comment: I wish i worked for a company that follows all these rules.. sadly this is not the case

Comment: Sounds like you need QA testing after development where this would be picked up.

Comment: We asked for a full time QA hire a year ago.  I'm not holding my breath

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  Interfaces define what members an object must implement.  They cannot define members that an object *can't* implement.  You could potentially use your own custom, or third party code analysis tools, to identify cases like this, but there is nothing in the language itself that would support it.

Answer (score 2):

No it is not possible. Are you not trying to define a `class` itself here? Why do you really need an interface?

However, what you can achieve is make calls to your interface and not your class by doing

```
 IPerson person = new Person();
```

this way you limit the person object to access only the methods defined in your interface.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this, but not within the object and its a bit silly to use in construction of the object.  Using `Reflection`, you can check the `type` of an instance of your object and iterate through its properties, throwing an exception if the count or names of properties do not match your desired instance.  Please note that if you just check against the interface, implementing objects will pass, so you would check against the desired concrete type.  I am on my phone or I'd add some sample code, will try to return to this later.

Comment: Here is what we ended up doing, using reflection, i created a string that contains all the fields and name of a class.  I then got the HashCode of that string.  I put that in a const in a new class.  That class has one method which tests all the classes i dont want to change to get the current hashcode of the string with the original one.  If the class changes in the future, the hashcode will not match the one i hardcoded anymore and a message will pop up when the app launches.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this, but not within the object and its a bit silly to use in construction of the object.  Using `Reflection`, you can check the `type` of an instance of your object and iterate through its properties, throwing an exception if the count or names of properties do not match your desired instance.  Please note that if you just check against the interface, implementing objects will pass, so you would check against the desired concrete type.   I'm on my phone so no sample code.  Will try to return to this later.